# .net Web Application set start page by code

Tags: .net

When creating a web application that doesn't have a "~/default.aspx" page, we would like to set the starting page to be "~/Pages/MyStartPage.aspx".

I know that the starting page property can be set in the IIS, or when we go to Project->Properties->Web-> and Set the Starting action to "Specific Page"=Pages/MyStartPage.aspx

Those options are not suitable to me since i need to do it by code.

Is there a class or setting in web.config that i can change that does that for me?

Thanks,
Maxim

Comment: Note that the second of those options, Project->Properties->Web, is only the starting page for your debug session - it's not a property of the site or the debug web server.

Comment: You've said below that you want to reconfigure IIS's document list in code. Which version of IIS? The metabase access mechanism changed in IIS 7. Where do you want to change this from - from your web site code? What user is your site running as, will it definitely have permission to edit the IIS metabase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only option is to create a trivial Default.aspx page which generates a `Response.Redirect` to the other page.

The problem is that IIS does not ask your application what the starting URL should be; instead it tries the first one in its list against your application. So I don't think this can be configured inside your application.

If your site is set up to pass all requests to ASP.NET regardless of whether the file on disk exists (i.e. a wildcard mapping in IIS) then you can probably intercept the original ~/ request in global.asax and route that in code there. But if you can't configure the default document yourself in IIS I'd doubt you can set that up either - and setting up a wildcard mapping is I think a far too generally disruptive solution to just implement this one case anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no way to add a value to this list that IIS keeps? This is what i am looking for...

Comment: Oh, you want to programmatically change the IIS configuration? Sorry, I'd misunderstood - I'd assumed you didn't have permission to change your IIS configuration at your hosting provider or similar. I'll comment on the Q since this is more general.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting this in Default.aspx?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Response.Redirect("~/Pages/MyStartPage.aspx");
}
```

Or use `Server.Transfer` instead if you prefer.  You can even use fancy switching logic to send people to different places if your heart so desires.

Comment: I don't have a Default.aspx page, and i don't want to create one that his only purpose is to redirect. Is there another option?

Comment: No.  Just create one; it's the simplest and most reliable way, apart from updating the IIS configuration which you've already dismissed.